# React Native Arrays Filtering Issue

Tags: arrays, react-native, filter

Below is a sample json data. I want to list fruit names based on a value found in the properties string. But I couldn't do that. I will be glad if you help me.

```js
[
    {"Fruit":"Apple","Specifiers":["Green Peel","Red Peel","Yellow Peel","Spherical","From Trees"]},
    {"Fruit":"WaterMelon","Specifiers":["Green Peel","Spherical","From Hebalecous"]},
    {"Fruit":"Grape","Specifiers":["Green Peel","Red Peel","Spherical","From Semi Trees"]}
]
```

Sample: if i choose **"From Trees"** i should result is **apple**

The React native code block is as follows. Where I make wrong?

```js
    import React, { Component } from "react";
    import { Text, View } from "react-native";

    const Datajson = 

        [
            {"Fruit":"Apple",
             "Specfy":["Green Peel","Red Peel","Yellow Peel","Spherical","From Trees"]
            },
    
           {"Fruit":"WaterMelon",
            "Specfy":["Green Peel","Spherical","From Hebalecous"]
           },
    
          {"Fruit":"Grape",
           "Specfy":["Green Peel","Red Peel","Spherical","From Semi Trees"]
          }
       ]

    class jsonArrayToList extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View>
            { /* It' ok Good Results*/
              Datajson
                  .filter(Fruits=>Fruits.Fruit==="Grape")
                  .map(FilteredData=>(<View><Text>{FilteredData.Specfy}</Text></View>))
     
            }
            { /* It's wrong Not Running*/
              Datajson
                  .filter(Fruits=>Fruits.Specfy==="From Trees")
                  .map(FilteredData=>(<View><Text>{FilteredData.Fruit}</Text></View>))
            }
         </View>
      
        );
      }
    }
    export default jsonArrayToList;
```

Issue is: If the fruit name matches, the specifies are listed. But if the specifies match, the fruit name is not taken.

How to get the result by changing the json data structure or code block? For your help
Thank you from now.

Answer (score 0):

`Specfy` inside any `Datajson.Fruit` is a array, not a text like `Fruit`, so you can't really filter for those in the same manner you filter for a regular string. To filter a array, which is what you did for the array `Datajson`, filtered by `Fruits.Fruit`. If I understood correctly, you objective is to return the fruit's name when a `Specfy` matches? Using JavaScript's native function `.contains()` to search for arrays would be a good solution. It returns `true` when any of the array's items *contains* the passed argument:

```js
...
{
          Datajson
              .filter(Fruits=>Fruits.Specfy.contains("From Trees")) // Will filter for any Fruit that has a `Specfy` matching "From Trees".
              .map(FilteredData=>(<View><Text>{FilteredData.Fruit}</View>)
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this code is'nt work. 
    {
          Datajson
              .filter(Fruits=>Fruits.Specfy.contains("From Trees")) // Will filter for any Fruit that 
    has a `Specfy` matching "From Trees".
              .map(FilteredData=>(<View><Text>{FilteredData.Fruit}</Text></View>))
    }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using "contains" use "includes"

```js
{ 
  Datajson
   .filter(Fruits=>Fruits.Specfy.includes("From Trees"))
     .map(FilteredData=>(<p>{FilteredData.Fruit}</p>))
}
```

This will return Apple.

Comment: Thank you very much grandmaster. These codes worked. If you'll excuse me, I have one more question. Let's select two or more items from the list above. May the result give us the fruit we have in common. For example: "Green Peel" and "Herbalecous"=WaterMelon. Another example is "Green Peel" and "Red Peel" the result is Grape and Apple.

Comment: yes we can .. here is the code ..  Datajson
                    .filter(Fruits =>{ return Fruits.Specfy.includes("Green Peel") &&
                    Fruits.Specfy.includes("Red Peel")})
                    .map(FilteredData => (<p>{FilteredData.Fruit}</p>)) .. this will return Grape and Apple.. based on your need you can use AND, OR conditions .